# About two measurable set question

Tags: lebesgue-measure

**Question:**

If $A$ and $B$ are measurable set,

> $ m(A) + m(B) = m(A\cup B) + m(A\cap B)$

equality is provided.(Lebesgue Measure)

**My Solution:**

> $m(B) = m(B\cap A) + m(B \cap A^\mathbb{c}) = m(B\cap A) + m(B
>  \setminus A)$
>
> $m(A \cup B ) = m((A \cup B) \cap A) + m((A \cup B) \cap A^\mathbb{c})
>  = m(A) + m(B  \setminus A)$

So, Would it be equal?

---

> $m((A \cup B) \cap A^\mathbb{c}) = m(B  \setminus A)$

---

If it's equal

> $  m(B \setminus A) = m(A \cup B ) - m(A)$
>
> $  m(B \setminus A) = m(B ) - m(A \cap B)$

hence,

> $ m(A) + m(B) = m(A\cup B) + m(A\cap B)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(A \cup B) \cap A^C=(A\cap A^C)\cup (B \cap A^C)=\emptyset\cup (B\setminus A)=B\setminus A$$